# Google Analytics, Dimensions & Metrics - How to?

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I've finally figured out how i connected to the Google Analytics, correct - and I'm now able to access data to some point. I'm using the google-api-php-client.

I can work with metrics just fine fx, by doing

```
     return $analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:' . $profileId,
    '7daysAgo',
    'today',
    'ga:sessions,ga:pageviews,ga:sessionDuration');
```

which will return me number of sessions, pageviews, and session duration. But now lets say I am interested in using some of the dimensions as well - Maybe i want the query return site usage data for all traffic by search engine, sorted by pageviews in descending order.

```
   dimensions=ga:source
   metrics=ga:pageviews,ga:sessionDuration,ga:exits         
   filters=ga:medium==cpa,ga:medium==cpc,ga:medium==cpm,ga:medium==cpp,ga:medium==cpv,ga:medium==organic,ga:medium==ppc
   sort=-ga:pageviews
```

the data_ga->get function calls for the following parameters: $ids, $startDate, $endDate, $metrics, $optParams = array()

I tried supplying the dimensions and filters in a array, but it returns me the following errors

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'type' in
>   xxxxxxxxx/src/Google/Service/Resource.php on line 269
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'location' in
>   xxxxxxxxx/src/Google/Service/Resource.php on line 272
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'location' in
>   xxxxxxxxx/src/Google/Service/Resource.php on line 274

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dimensions are not required so there for they are part of option parameters.

```
//Adding Dimensions
$params = array('dimensions' => 'ga:userType'); 
// requesting the data  
$data = $service->data_ga->get("ga:89798036", "2014-12-14", "2014-12-  14", "ga:users,ga:sessions", $params );
```

Filters and sort can also be added to the $parms array